# is it possible to convert a DIV to image with any javascript library

Tags: javascript, image, html

I'm thinking of this since last three weeks is there any way to convert a specific DIV to a images file like jpg.  Is there any javascript library that can perform this. Or may be is not possible on web. Free to share your thought and ideas. Thanks.               Sheyviruz

Comment: What and why are you trying this?

Comment: It is impossible! @Sheyviruz. Because javascript can not save file.

Comment: I asked the same thing ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520390/javascript-library-to-take-screenshot-of-web-page

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725427/converting-a-div-content-to-an-image-via-javascript